# Simple, physical explanations for Hadamard behaviour of two-point functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The two-point function of local quantum fields on a curved spacetime exhibits a singularity of a very particular form, known as Hadamard form, for null separated points $(x,y)$ (including the coincident case where $x=y$). For example, if $\phi(x)$ is a scalar field in $4$-dimensions, then the Hadamard form of the anti-commutator correlation function (see for example [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01196934))

$$ G(x,y) = \langle \phi(x) \phi(y) + \phi(y) \phi(x) \rangle \, ,$$

is given by

$$ G(x,y) = \frac{u(x,y)}{\sigma} + v(x,y) \ln \sigma + w(x,y) \, , $$

where $\sigma$ is half the square of the geodesic distance between $x,y$ (the curved space analog of $(x-y)^2/2$), and $u,v,w$ are smooth functions of $x,y$. The first two terms diverge at zero and null separation, where $\sigma = 0$.

My only physical understanding of the requirement that a correlator exhibit this Hadamard form is that the short-distance singularities indicate that the state where the expectation value is being taken in is "close" to the flat space vacuum *in the UV*. There is no unique vacuum in curved space, but any candidate vacuum should probably look like the flat space vacuum on short enough distance scales.

My question is: are there other, simple and physical understandings of the meaning of this singularity?

Comment: The leading $1/\sigma$ singularity should be a 4d version of the Coulombic potential around a point charge.  The log presumably comes because obtaining the Green's function involves solving a second order differential equation in in the variable $\sigma$ with characteristic exponents -1 and 0.  The series expansion near $\sigma = 0$ will then naturally involve logs because the difference between the exponents is an integer.

Comment: This seems plausable, but I don't see why this should be true? The field in this case is a scalar, not a gauge field capable of producing a Coulombic potential, it may be charged or uncharged, and it may be massive or massless.

Comment: In both cases, the relevant partial differential equation is Poisson's equation.